# Image manipulation with css or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a minor question about image manipulation on websites.

I got the question to implement some form of rating system where users can rate something for 1-2 or 3 stars. Only one star is shown per item. The request is that the star updates like the stars below:

[image: Rating of 100%, full star] = 100%

[image: Rating of 70%, part of star] = 70%

Now comes the question: is there some form of css or javascript magic which allows me to do this without using multiple images.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this.

1. First, the star image needs to be displayed.
2. Then over that star, a radial progress bar will be displayed with reverse progress. The color of one side of it will be white and another side transparent.

   Visit https://codepen.io/jo-asakura/pen/stFHi to know how you can do the radial progress bar.

### CSS

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:700);

.size(@w, @h) {
  height: @h;
  width: @w;
}

// --
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  background: #ecf0f1;
  color: #444;
  font-family: 'Lato', Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.set-size {
  font-size: 10em;
}

.charts-container:after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

@bg: #34495e;
@size: 1em;

.pie-wrapper {
  .size(@size, @size);
  float: left;
  margin: 15px;
  position: relative;

  &:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: both;
  }

  .pie {
    .size(100%, 100%);
    clip: rect(0, @size, @size, @size / 2);
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;

    .half-circle {
      .size(100%, 100%);
      border: @size / 10 solid #3498db;
      border-radius: 50%;
      clip: rect(0, @size / 2, @size, 0);
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
    }
  }

  .label {
    @font-size: @size / 4;
    @font-size-redo: @size * 4;

    background: @bg;
    border-radius: 50%;
    bottom: @font-size-redo / 10;
    color: #ecf0f1;
    cursor: default;
    display: block;
    font-size: @font-size;
    left: @font-size-redo / 10;
    line-height: @font-size-redo * .65;
    position: absolute;
    right: @font-size-redo / 10;
    text-align: center;
    top: @font-size-redo / 10;

    .smaller {
      color: #bdc3c7;
      font-size: .45em;
      padding-bottom: 20px;
      vertical-align: super;
    }
  }

  .shadow {
    .size(100%, 100%);
    border: @size / 10 solid #bdc3c7;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }

  &.style-2 {
    .label {
      background: none;
      color: #7f8c8d;

      .smaller {
        color: #bdc3c7;
      }
    }
  }

  &.progress-30 {
    .draw-progress(30, #3498db);
  }

  &.progress-60 {
    .draw-progress(60, #9b59b6);
  }

  &.progress-90 {
    .draw-progress(90, #e67e22);
  }

  &.progress-45 {
    .draw-progress(45, #1abc9c);
  }

  &.progress-75 {
    .draw-progress(75, #8e44ad);
  }

  &.progress-95 {
    .draw-progress(95, #e74c3c);
  }
}

.pie-wrapper--solid {
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;

  &:before {
    border-radius: 0 100% 100% 0 / 50%;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 50%;
    transform-origin: left;
  }

  .label {
    background: transparent;
  }

  &.progress-65 {
    .draw-progress--solid(65, #e67e22, @bg);
  }

  &.progress-25 {
    .draw-progress--solid(25, #9b59b6, @bg);
  }

  &.progress-88 {
    .draw-progress--solid(88, #3498db, @bg);
  }
}

// --
.draw-progress(@progress, @color) when (@progress <= 50) {
  .pie {
    .right-side {
      display: none;
    }
  }
}

.draw-progress(@progress, @color) when (@progress > 50) {
  .pie {
    clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, auto);

    .right-side {
      transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
  }
}

.draw-progress(@progress, @color) {
  .pie {
    .half-circle {
      border-color: @color;
    }

    .left-side {
      @rotate: @progress * 3.6;
      transform: rotate(~'@{rotate}deg');
    }
  }
}

.draw-progress--solid(@progress, @color, @bg) when (@progress <= 50) {
  &:before {
    background: @bg;
    transform: rotate((100 - (50 - @progress)) / 100 * 360deg * -1);
  }
}

.draw-progress--solid(@progress, @color, @bg) when (@progress > 50) {
  &:before {
    background: @color;
    transform: rotate((100 - @progress) / 100 * 360deg);
  }
}

.draw-progress--solid(@progress, @color, @bg) {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, @color 50%, @bg 50%);
}
```

### HTML

```
<div class="set-size charts-container">
  <div class="pie-wrapper progress-30">
    <span class="label">30<span class="smaller">%</span></span>
    <div class="pie">
      <div class="left-side half-circle"></div>
      <div class="right-side half-circle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="pie-wrapper progress-60">
    <span class="label">60<span class="smaller">%</span></span>
    <div class="pie">
      <div class="left-side half-circle"></div>
      <div class="right-side half-circle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="pie-wrapper progress-90">
    <span class="label">90<span class="smaller">%</span></span>
    <div class="pie">
      <div class="left-side half-circle"></div>
      <div class="right-side half-circle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="pie-wrapper progress-45 style-2">
    <span class="label">45<span class="smaller">%</span></span>
    <div class="pie">
      <div class="left-side half-circle"></div>
      <div class="right-side half-circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="shadow"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="pie-wrapper progress-75 style-2">
    <span class="label">75<span class="smaller">%</span></span>
    <div class="pie">
      <div class="left-side half-circle"></div>
      <div class="right-side half-circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="shadow"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="pie-wrapper progress-95 style-2">
    <span class="label">95<span class="smaller">%</span></span>
    <div class="pie">
      <div class="left-side half-circle"></div>
      <div class="right-side half-circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="shadow"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="pie-wrapper pie-wrapper--solid progress-65">
    <span class="label">65<span class="smaller">%</span></span>
  </div>

  <div class="pie-wrapper pie-wrapper--solid progress-25">
    <span class="label">25<span class="smaller">%</span></span>
  </div>

  <div class="pie-wrapper pie-wrapper--solid progress-88">
    <span class="label">88<span class="smaller">%</span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use image sprite, so **technically**, you only load one image.

Comment: This one image then consist of multiple images?

Comment: yes, apologies as i also do not know the magical css or js for this. but this is the most optimized way to achieve what you need. just give the class for each desired image on page load or programatically change the image by changing the class trough js.

Answer (score 0):

I'd overlay a pie-segment on the image, and just control it's size. Just make sure it's colour is the same as the background of the page, if possible.

See: https://codepen.io/sandeepshah/pen/eEqLpv

```
<div class="pie"></div>

.pie {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

.pie:BEFORE {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  left: -100px;
  border-radius: 100px 0 0 100px;
  transform-origin: right center;
  background-color: red;
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}
```

Use the final attribute "transform" to control it's size.

Answer (score 0):

You can use html5 canvas (read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp) and [this](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/canvas_coordinates.asp)). Just create square with background image of full star and change canvas dimensions using jquery. Or create div with 6 images (one corner of the star turned to a certain angle). And make only certain parts visible (example: for 50% hide 3 images)